# How to declare mutableListOf of arrays?

Tags: kotlin

I want to declare mutableListOf arrays but I don't know how. Google shows me examples like var mutableList1 = mutableListOf<Int>() and etc, but not arrays case(((

```
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var mutableList1 = mutableListOf<Arrays>()
    var mutableList2 = mutableListOf(arrayOf<Int>())    //works, but it contains empty array:(
    mutableList1.add(arrayOf(1,1))                      //error
}
```

Comment: why? it's a bad practice, better to use .map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```kotlin
val list = mutableListOf<Array<Int>>()
list.add(arrayOf(1, 1))
```

**Edit:** As [Animesh Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65161060/how-to-declare-mutablelistof-of-arrays/65161091#comment115204882_65161091) (thanks!) has pointed out in the comments, if you don't need boxed integers (no nulls in the arrays), you can use the primitive arrays instead and avoid their overhead:

```kotlin
val list = mutableListOf<IntArray>()
list.add(intArrayOf(1, 1))
```

Comment: @biomusor glad to hear that :). Could you mark the answer as accepted, if it has solved your problem?

Comment: of course) Stackoverflow says me that I can do it in 3 minutes)

Comment: @biomusor probably use `IntArray` to reduce overhead of unnecessary autoboxings.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use mutableListOf
for example

```
val distributionList = mutableListOf<ParticipantDTO>()
participantVolumeList.forEach {
    distributionList.add(
        ParticipantDTO(
            participantUuid = it.get(PARTICIPANT_VOLUMES.PARTICIPANT_UUID)
        )
    )
}
```

better rewrite to

```
val distributionList = participantVolumeList.map { mapToParticipant(it) }

private fun mapToParticipant(
    participantVolumesRec: JParticipantRecord
): ParticipantDTO {
    return ParticipantDTO().apply {
        participantUuid = participantVolumesRec.get(PARTICIPANT_VOLUMES.PARTICIPANT_UUID)
    }
}
```